# How can I distribute my task to all worker nodes in gcp? I am using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a cluster with 1 master (clus-m) and two worker nodes(clus-w-0, clus-w-1) in gcp dataproc.
Now using pyspark rdd, I want to distribute one task so that all the nodes get involved.
Below is my code snippet.

```
def pair_dist(row):
    dissimlarity = 0
    Z = row[0].split(',')
    X = row[1].split(',')

    for j in range(len(Z)):
        if Z[j] != X[j]:
            dissimlarity += 1

    return str(dissimlarity) + **os.uname()[1]**

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
rdd = sc.textFile( "input.csv" )

rdd = sc.parallelize(rdd.take(5))
rdd = rdd.cartesian(rdd)
dist = rdd.map(lambda x: pair_dist(x)).collect()
dist = np.array(dist).reshape((5,5))
print(dist)

sc.stop()
```

To check whether it is happened properly or not I put the host name with the result.
But I always get the host name **clus-m** in result not the worker nodes' host name.

**Output:**
[0clus-m 2clus-m......
 1clus-m 0clus-m.......] 5x5

Please suggest what exactly I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

To distribute work, your input dataset has to be sharded. Since you're using `sc.textFile( "input.csv" )` you will have a single mapper reading the file.

If for instance the input dataset is substantially multiplied through transformations, you could `RDD.repartition` to make subsequent operations better parallelized.

Your best bet will be to split the input into multiple files.

[Spark programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#external-datasets) has these points that are relevant to your question:

> All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support
>   running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For
>   example, you can use textFile("/my/directory"),
>   textFile("/my/directory/*.txt"), and textFile("/my/directory/*.gz").
>
> The textFile method also takes an optional second argument for
>   controlling the number of partitions of the file. By default, Spark
>   creates one partition for each block of the file (blocks being 128MB
>   by default in HDFS), but you can also ask for a higher number of
>   partitions by passing a larger value. Note that you cannot have fewer
>   partitions than blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I did the partition and want to check the hostname again. But got the same result.
Below is the code snippet.
<code>
def hostname(row):
    return os.uname()[1] 
 
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv", header=None)
data = numpy.array(data)
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd = rdd.repartition(3)
print(rdd.getNumPartitions())    
rdd = rdd.cartesian(rdd)
print(rdd.count())
dist = rdd.map(lambda x: hostname(x)).collect()
dist = np.array(dist).reshape((120,120))
print(dist)
</code>

Comment: Basically I want to check the collection of map() should show all the vm's host name

Comment: Or I need to manually configure the hadoop first? like mentioning different slave nodes, ip in /etc/host file?

Comment: Dataproc should just work out of the box, no need to configure anything. Please keep in mind that distributing data between nodes adds latency so Spark/Yarn will sensibly choose to scale up before scaling out. Additional answers you may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531816 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615354